# Javascript array to enum

Tags: javascript, arrays, enums

I need to build an enum from a javascript array.
(I need it to populate a query)

```
var myArray = [113214, 432423, 65465, 65654]; //something like this
var enum = ('113214', '432423', '65465', '65654'); //into something like this
```

then use the enum variable as a parameter to populate my query like this:

```
SELECT * ... WHERE id IN (enum);
```

In this moment my query looks like

```
SELECT * ... WHERE id IN ([0934ED47E088, 0CEAC518, 3F01267E1368]);
```

I need the single quote for every string and no brackets.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Could you add concrete usage to understand what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by "enum" in this context? Normally an "enum" has symbolic names that map to values (sometimes implicit values starting typically with 0, other times explicitly given), but your example pseudo-code doesn't seem to be doing that...

Comment: what is enums in javascript?

Comment: how does the query look like?

Comment: JS does not have enums. The closest you can do is an object that holds your enum value as key. Depending on the editor used, that might even add in autocomplete for those values. But that's about it.

Comment: @vlaz, or use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: @NinaScholz a Set would also work but it's not quite the same - with an object you can have something like `{ERROR: 0, WARN: 1, DEBUG: 3, OFF: 4}` where the "enum" (in quotes) value maps to something else. This is closer to classical enums in other languages. A Set will just ensure you have non-repeating values. Neither of these really capture "real" enums although both will do partly what a "real" enum does. There simply is no enum in JS. With the update, it seems OP merely wanted unique values, so a Set is more appropriate, while an array could also be used (if there is no ES6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and build a string with single quotes around the values.

```js
var myArray = [113214, 432423, 65465, 65654, 'abc'],
    stringified = myArray.map(function (a) {
        return '\'' + a + '\'';
    }).join(', '),
    query = 'SELECT * ... WHERE id IN (' + stringified + ');'

console.log(query);
```